# Cannot call a plugin model function from a different model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I have a model that needs to go through specific plugins and call a function inside of their model. I am able to call find('all'), but not a custom function inside of the model.

Model calling Plugin's model function:

```
public function copy($id){
        $this->id = $id;
        $original = $this->read();
        $new = $original['DocModule'];
        unset($new['id']);
        if(!$this->save($new)){
            CakeLog::debug("Could not copy DocModule in DocModule.php");
            return false;
        }
        $newId = $this->getLastInsertID();

        $modelName = $original['Module']['name'];              

        $this->{$modelName} = ClassRegistry::init($modelName.'.'.$modelName);
        CakeLog::debug(print_r($this->{$modelName}->find('all'),1));
        $this->{$modelName}->copyModule($newId, $id);
    }
```

Plugin's model function:

```
public function copyModule($newDocModId, $oldDocModId) {        
    $old = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('doc_module_id' => $oldDocModId), 'recursive' => -1));
    $new = $old;
    unset($new['Weather']['id']);
    $new['Weather']['doc_module_id'] = $newDocModId;
    if (!$this->save($new)) {
        CakeLog::debug("Could not copy weather.  Old = " . $oldDocModId . " | New = " . $newDocModId);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure CakePHP is loading the right model? (i.e. try `debug(get_class($this->{$modelName}));`) Do you have multiple models sharing the same className? (e.g. `PluginA.Foo` and `PluginB.Foo`) My experience is that only using the 'plugin' as 'namespace' isn't reliable if both models have the same className.

Comment: `ClassRegistry::init($modelName.'.'.$modelName);` The first one should probably be $pluginName.

Comment: The plugin name and model name are the same. I did verify that they correct plugin's model was being loaded and it was. I also verified that not only by looking at the model object that is loaded (print_r($model)), but also running find('all') on that model.

Comment: Here is the error I get in the log: "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'copyModule' at line 1"  copyModule is the function name I am trying to call.

Comment: Based on thaJeztah's comments, I tried: I added a new model in the plugin with a different name than the plugin's. I was able to call the function just fine. Evidently, your models' names should be different than the plugin's. However, this is the only place that I have seen this as being an issue with the names being the same.

Comment: @tewman that's the reason I suggested debugging `get_class()`; CakePHP will sometimes generate a 'generic' model if a model does not exist; `find('all')` will work in those situations, but custom methods obviously not, because you'll be effectively using the `AppModel`. Also having multiple models with the same name may confuse CakePHP; CakePHP will use the first model it finds with that name. I am *not* aware that `Plugin.Plugin` as ModelName doesn't work, this *may be a bug*, please test this further with other names for the plugin/model as well, otherwise post a bug report